# How to call Dockerized R Plumber API from an external source?

Tags: r, docker, api, deployment, plumber

I have created an R Plumber API, and deploy it in a Docker image.

Dockerfile:

```
ARG R_VERSION=latest

FROM rocker/r-ver:${R_VERSION}

# install the linux libraries needed for plumber
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y \
  libssl-dev \
  libcurl4-gnutls-dev

COPY / /

# Making home & test folders 
RUN Rscript required-packages/required-packages.R

# Giving permission to tests to run
RUN chmod +x tests/run_tests.sh

# Run Tests  
RUN tests/run_tests.sh

# open port 7575 to traffic
EXPOSE 7575

# when the container starts, start the main.R script
ENTRYPOINT ["Rscript", "./main.R"]
```

main.R

```
library(plumber)

r <- plumb("./plumber.R")
r$run(port = 7575, host = "0.0.0.0")
```

I run the container with the following command.

```
docker run --rm -p 7575:7575 'container-name'
```

On the machine, `http://localhost:7575/echo` works perfectly fine. However, I cannot call the API from an external computer with `http://ip_address:7575/echo`.

What could be the problem? As far as I know, the 7575 port is open.